# Angular - Focus lost following navigation from component back to page

Tags: angular, accessibility, focus, angular-routing

For a given component profile, it uses the button (edit name)
when the button is pressed -> the user is navigated to a new component edit name
the user saves the name and is returned to the profile
A notification edit name success appears

The focus is returned to the page and not the panel profile where the name is.

What is the best way to return focus to the panel? does this seem possible?